# Adding domain path to django html templates

Tags: django, waitress

I am serving a django app with a combination of nginx reverse proxy and waitress. In the nginx configuration the app is linked via a location:

```
location /app/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8686/;
    }
```

While the app runs on via `waitress` on port 8686.

Now, if I go to the domain.com/app, I the index page is served correctly. Though, my django html template contains the following link:

```
 <p> You are not logged in.</p> <a href="/accounts/login"><button>Login</button></a>
```

When I press that button I get to

`domain.com/accounts/login`

but it should be

`domain.com/app/accounts/login`

I wonder how to change the code so that it works independently of where the app is linked.

In `urls.py` the urls are included like this:

```
urlpatterns:  = [...,
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the url in `urls.py` (most probably you've already done this) and then use `reverse` in templates:

```
<a href="{% url 'foo:bar' %}"><button>Login</button></a>
```

Then rewrite URLs in nginx to make your app think that you're accessing `/accounts/login` instead of `/app/accounts/login`:

```
location /app/ {
    rewrite ^/app(.*)$ $1 last;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8686/;
}
```

Docs:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-url
2. https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: The url is included with urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))]

Comment: Actually, you may ignore the `urls.py` advice. Everything you need to solve your problem is URL rewrite.